# How to match a dataframe df1 column string to another dataframe df2 column (multiple strings) and get value from another column is df2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Hi I am trying to write a query that will match DF1_NAME with DF2_ALT_NAME (knowing that DF2_ALT_NAME may have several values to compare to and if there is a match get DF2_STANDARD_NAME value) and then fill-in DF1_STANDARD_NAME with value from DF2_Standard_NAME.

For example:
In DF1_NAME I have value "Slau", I need to check in DF2.DF2_ALT_NAME all the values, it is not necessarily an exact match:
I need to find "Slau" within "Slau,Slough,Слау" and then get DF2_Standard_NAME value: "Slough".

DF1:

| id | DF1_NAME | DF1_STANDARD_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 88456 | Moscow |  |
| 88457 | Slau |  |
| 88458 | Salford |  |
| 88459 | Dubai |  |
| 88460 | Sort |  |

DF2:

| id | DF2_ALT_NAME | DF2_Standard_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 66 | Slau,Slough,Слау | Slough |
| 7 | Sheringem,shryngham,Шерингем | Sheringham |
| 8 | Salford,Salfordas,Solfard,Solford,salfwrd | Salford |
| 88 | Ryhope | Ryhope |
| 999 | Rhosan ar Wy,Ross,Ross on Wye | Ross on Wye |

Thank you for your help

My Python is not that good, I tried loops like: for i in enumerate, I tried fin() but my loops never ends...
Can someone help me figure out how to write the code, would greatly appreciate...

Comment: you can turn your `DF2_ALT_NAME` column into a column of lists of strings, `DF2.DF2_ALT_NAME = DF2.DF2_ALT_NAME.str.split(',')`. Then, you can use logic of [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70345745/how-can-merge-with-key-and-list-of-keys-in-pandas-dataframe) for your merge. Basically, you want to do a `DF2.explode('DF2_ALT_NAME')` and then `pd.merge`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isIn` :

```
df1["DF1_STANDARD_NAME"] = df2[df2.DF2_ALT_NAME.isin(df1.DF1_NAME)]["DF2_STANDARD_NAME"]
```

This will fill DF1 "`DF1_STANDARD_NAME`" with DF2 "`STANDARD_NAME`" in case DF1 "`DF1_NAME`" matches DF2 "`DF2_ALT_NAME`". If there is no match, the cell value will be `NaN`.

If you want to remove the `NaN`, don't forget the command :

```
df1 = df1.fillna('')
```

OR using `inPlace` :

```
df1.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But it is not an exact match, the value might be in the middle of other values: In my code I use DF2.DF2_ALT_NAME.str.replace(",", " " ) as to find a match but cannot get it right so far...

Answer (score 1):

First, explode `DF2` so that each name has its own row. Then, merge on that row.
For example:

```
#split alt_name into list of strings 
DF2.DF2_ALT_NAME = DF2.DF2_ALT_NAME.str.split(',')
#explode so each alt_name has its own row
DF2 = DF2.explode('DF2_ALT_NAME')

#now, merge on the alt_name
DF1 = DF1.merge(DF2, left_on = 'DF1_NAME', right_on = 'DF2_ALT_NAME', how='left')
#fill in DF1 column
DF1['DF1_STANDARD_NAME'].fillna(DF1['DF2_Standard_NAME'], inplace=True)

#drop extra DF2 column from DF1
DF1.drop(columns = ['DF2_Standard_NAME'], inplace = True)
```

This could be shortened with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842140/pandas-merge-dataframes-with-shared-column-fillna-in-left-with-right), where you use `.update`.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this and it did the job, thanks!

you can turn your DF2_ALT_NAME column into a column of lists of strings, DF2.DF2_ALT_NAME = DF2.DF2_ALT_NAME.str.split(','). Then, you can use logic of this question/answer for your merge. Basically, you want to do a DF2.explode('DF2_ALT_NAME') and then pd.merge. –
34jbonz

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).